# Singularity: bind directory with same name as host

Tags: bind, singularity-container

I've a directory (/home/user/data) that I need to bind to /data in a singularity container. So something like :

```
singularity shell --bind /home/user/data:/data container.simg
```

However on the host machine there is already a /data directory. I know that --contain parameter allows me to not share the host filesystem but I only need to "mask" the host /data directory in order to bind host /home/user/data to container's /data. Is there a way to do that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you can mask your subdirectory with this:

```
singularity shell --bind /home/user/data:/data --bind /dev/null:/home/user/data container.simg
```